# MSBUILD : error MSB1009: The project file does not exist. Modificator: INSTALL.vcxproj when trying debug.bat

Tags: godot

im trying to use GDNative from Godot. When I use the debug.bat command in the godot-native-example it always appears

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The error is pretty straight forward ( a file is not found). So you likely forgot a step. Did you use this example? https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdnative/gdnative_cpp_example.html

Comment: Im trying to run debug.bat into godot-native-example folder. Im using this tutorial:  https://github.com/samsface/godot-native-example/